# menu does not inflate

Tags: android, menu

I am trying to inflate android menu but I fail to inflate it:

here is my menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemPrefs"
        android:background="#f000"
        android:title="@string/titlePrefs"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp">
    </item>
</menu>
```

and here is where I inflate my main activity:

```
@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

I am using LG G3 and menu is not showing :-(

thanks for your help

Comment: Try adding this to item line :-  android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi thanks for your answers, apparently, my menu was set in action bar and hidden.
To force menu to appear I modified res/values/styles.xml like this:

res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"> </style>
</resources>
```

and res/values/styles.xml(v21)

```
<resources>
     <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>
</resources>
```

and then every thing went smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
android:id="@+id/itemPrefs"
android:background="#f000"
android:title="@string/titlePrefs"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using activity, for Showing menu you need to use `app:showAsAction ="always"` property in your menu item an write menu header as

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
     <item
         android:id="@+id/action_cart"
         android:icon="@drawable/cart"
         android:orderInCategory="100"
         android:title="@string/abc_search_hint"
         app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

If you are using Fragment, you need to set a property `setHasOptionMenu(true)` for enabling option menu item to be visible

Otherwise alternative solution is to add item dynamically, that will work definitely i.e.

```
        menu.add(Menu.NONE,0,Menu.NONE,"")
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.rating))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.cart)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```